# How to make XAML editing with Resharper more responsive

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resharper

I have been using the trial version of ReSharper (v 7.1.2) on Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition. I'm using an HP Elitebook 8570w, equipped with an i7-3610QM CPU and 4GB of RAM, so performance shouldn't be an issue. And it works quite well, but for some reason it chokes up really bad when I'm editing XAML. Whenever I'm typing something it lags with every single keystroke.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? If not, is there a way to disable Resharper only for XAML files?

Comment: [Responsive XAML editing with ReSharper](http://blog.lebosquain.net/2012/08/responsive-xaml-editing-with-resharper/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the article, it seems to be much more responsive now. Could you post it as an answer. If you can, I'll change the subject of the question to "How to make XAML editing with Resharper more responsive", so it will be easier to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julien Lebosquain provides a solution on his blog.  It involves changing the "Open With" setting of the XAML files to an ordinary text editor, so that they don't automatically open in Visual Studio.  He also has a couple of registry hacks, and a Resharper plugin.

The blog article is here:
http://blog.lebosquain.net/2012/08/responsive-xaml-editing-with-resharper/

Comment: The link is broken unfortunately

Comment: @Benlitz: Surely this isn't still a problem?  I use Resharper where I work now, and when it gets in the way I just turn it off (There's a "Suspend" button in Tools/Options/Resharper).  See also http://blog.lebosquain.net/?s=xaml+resharper, which contains the original blog post (his link to the actual blog post is the same broken link as the one posted here).

Comment: With Reshaper 9 on Visual Studio 2015, it has never been as much a problem as today. It is utterly slow, and the fact that VS uses Roselyn and is 32bits makes the GC go crazy and freeze the whole stuff. Plus, It seems that there's a bug somewhere and when I use the default Text editor instead of the xaml one, at some point I cannot open xaml files anymore: VS states that the file is already open but it is actually not. I might detail all my issues in a new question on SO if I can't find a proper solution.